# Show $2<p^{2}<3$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis

I am working through a sample problem to show that E is not compact for $E = \{p \in \mathbb{Q} | 2<p^{2}<3 \}$. E is not compact, and i wish to use the theorem that if a set K$\subset X$ is compact than for every infinite subset $E \subset K$ has a limit in K.

now clearly $2<p^{2}<3$ has no least element, and no greatest element.  then we know that the sequence $\{p_n\}$ does not converge to $\sqrt{3}$  so this shows that the limit $\sqrt{3}$ is not attained, however, it is not even in the set $E = \{p \in \mathbb{Q} | 2<p^{2}<3 \}$.  so how should I use the sequential compactness to finish the proof?

The other idea is that if the this set E has no greatest element, then doesn't this imply that there exists a sequence $\{p_n\}$ which does not have a limit in E, and goes to infinity?  intuitively this makes some sense....

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $E$ is compact. For $\sqrt{2}$, there exists a sequence $\{x_n: x_n\in E\}$ such that converges $\sqrt{2}$. Since $E$ is compact, then $\sqrt{2} \in E$, however, $\sqrt{2}^2=2$, which is a contradiction!

Comment: my problem is that we have a strict inequality which means that $\sqrt{2}$ is not in our set to begin with.

Comment: That's exactly the point. If E is compact, he is closed and bounded (he is bounded). So if you suppose that it is closed you can find a sequence that converges towards an element of its closure (say $\sqrt 2$ ) and the limit of the sequence will be in the set E, which is obviously a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is closed and bounded.  Closed and bounded implies compact for real numbers, but not for rationals.  Consider $E^c$.  This set is open because you can find a neighborhood around every point.  Therefore its complement, $E$, is closed.

If you assumed it was compact, then it would have a finite subcover over the whole set.  Then find a point in $E$ that isn't contained in the subcover.